# Using .map() to add incrementing values to JS objects

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know if one can use `.map()` to dynamically change the added value to JS objects.

For example, a static use of `.map()` allows to add a similar ID to all objects of the array.

```
friends = [
          {
            "age": 10,
            "name": "Castillo"
          },
          {
            "age": 11,
            "name": "Daugherty"
          },
          {
            "age": 12,
            "name": "Travis"
          }
        ]

// Static mapping --> adds 1 to all objects
friends_static=friends;
friends.map(elem => elem["id"] = 1);
console.log(friends_static)
```

This returns `[{age=10, name="Castillo", id=1}, {age=11, name="Daugherty", id=1}, {age=12, name="Travis", id=1}]`

Is it possible to add a unique ID which increments by 1 for each object in a similar way?

Cf. the illustrative [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc28/Lntdbav4/3/) and example code below. I know the `1++` is not legal, but just shows the idea I'm trying to realize.

```
//Dynamic mapping? --> should add 1,2,3...to objects incrementally
/*
friends_dynamic=friends;
friends.map(elem => elem["id"] = 1++);
console.log(friends_dynamic)
*/
```

This should return `[{age=10, name="Castillo", id=1}, {age=11, name="Daugherty", id=2}, {age=12, name="Travis", id=3}]`

Comment: Why `.map()` specifically? That's used for creating a new array, but you don't seem to want one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```js
const friends = [
    {
        "age": 10,
        "name": "Castillo"
    },
    {
        "age": 11,
        "name": "Daugherty"
    },
    {
        "age": 12,
        "name": "Travis"
    }
]

friends.forEach((friend, index) => friend.id = index + 1);

console.log(friends)
```

Comment: Yes, whilst you *could* use map to achieve the same result, it would be really confusing to do so, as the semantics of `map()` suggest you're creating something *new* from something else. If I see `forEach()`, I'm prepared for a mutation such as this.

Comment: Thanks for the light @blaz @Ian! The reason I went for `.map()` is that I assumed it would be the quickest/most efficient approach. Could you confirm that this `forEach()` approach is at least equivalent in terms of speed for a larger object?   Furthermore, bonus question if you wouldn't mind: how could I make sure the `id`s are added to objects not randomly but ordered based on another value (e.g. increasing `age` values (assuming all ages are unique))?

Comment: @sc28: Curious why you thought `.map()` would be most efficient. Does it have anything to do with  a blog post?

Comment: With absolutely no data to back this up, `.map()` seems like it would be *less* efficient as [you're also creating an array of `n` elements which will presumably just be undefined](https://jsfiddle.net/ywd49t1u/)

Comment: @rock it was rather based on an unfounded hunch actually. I think read that the arrow-notation was a recent feature from ES6, so I inferred it would be a "modern", and so efficient approach. This [post](https://ryanpcmcquen.org/javascript/2015/10/25/map-vs-foreach-vs-for.html) actually seems to indicate that map would be slower then alternatives, so debunking my hunch.

Answer (score 17):

You could just use the `index` provided to the `Array#map` callback:

```
friends.map((friend, index) => Object.assign({}, friend, { id: index + 1 }))
```

It's not a good idea to mutate objects in `Array#map`. The whole purpose of the method is to return *new objects* that are mapped from the original objects. Thus use `Object.assign` to avoid mutation.

Of course, if you *wanted* mutation, thus just use `forEach` without mapping to new values. It would be more "semantically correct" in that case.

Comment: So `.forEach()` seems like a good solution for mutating the existing objects in the array, as the OP has requested, right?

Answer (score 2):

if you only need an incremental value from 0 on, you can simply use a counter and increment it, like this:

```
let id = 1;
friends.map(elem => {elem.id = id++;});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a local variable and increment it. As per method [definition](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
"The map() method calls the provided function once for each element in an array, in order". In Order would make sure that ids do not collide.

```js
friends = [
      {
        "age": 10,
        "name": "Castillo"
      },
      {
        "age": 11,
        "name": "Daugherty"
      },
      {
        "age": 12,
        "name": "Travis"
      }
    ]

// Static mapping --> adds 1 to all objects
friends_static=friends;
var i = 1;
friends_static.map(elem => elem["id"] = i++);
console.log(friends_static)

//Dynamic mapping? --> should add 1,2,3...to objects incrementally
/*
friends_dynamic=friends;
friends_dynamic.map(elem => elem["id"] = 1++);
console.log(friends_dynamic)
*/
```